# How to Change Brake Rotors on 2000 Nissan Frontier 2WD

Tags: brake-rotor

Anyone have pointers on how to change the disc brake rotors on a 2000 Nissan Frontier 2WD? I've got the calipers and pads off and noted the rotor is scored.  I'd like to just replace the rotors.  The rotors on most other vehicles come off easily when the calipers are removed.  Does not appear to be the case on this Nissan frontier though.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dust cap in the center of the hub (in the middle of the wheel stubs) remove the cotter pin (replace with new one on installation) remove the nut lock and then the nut. You should be able to pull the whole assembly off (rotor and hub) from the back side you should be able to get to the bolts that hold the rotor on the hub. Install in the reverse order.

**Spindle nut installation**

1. Tighten the spindle nut to 25 - 29 ft. lbs.
2. Spin the hub several times to fully seat the bearings.
3. Re-tighten the spindle nut to 25 - 29 ft. lbs.
4. Loosen the spindle nut 45 - 60 degrees and install the spindle nut cap and (new) cotter pin

Note if you are going to go that far I would defiantly repack the wheel bearings and replace the wheel seal.

I found an excellent tutorial at [www.howstuffinmycarworks.com](http://www.howstuffinmycarworks.com/Nissan_Frontier_brakes_1.html)

Comment: what if my truck doesn't have a spindle?

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the original question - perhaps you meant to comment on Larry's post? In answer to your question however, if your truck doesn't have a spindle (stub axle), the wheels will fall off...

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the rotors on a Nissan Frontier is slightly more complicated than with other vehicles. The hub and bearing assembly is bolted to the brake rotors, so you must deal with it as well as the brake caliper. If you need to change one brake rotor, there is a good chance that you will need to change both. This process can vary depending on the year of the truck and whether it has two- or four-wheel drive.

Stops you'll Need:
    Floor jack
    Jack stands
    Tire iron
    Wrench
    Wire
    Hammer and chisel
    Needle-nose pliers
    Locking pliers
    Brake rotor(s)
    Brake pads
    C-clamp
Source: http://www.ehow.com/how_7702448_replace-rotors-nissan-frontier.html